# Regarding SQL sum return result that is unreadable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Regarding SQL sum return result that is unreadable

I have this database record

```
select tran_final_net_bal from transaction where tran_account_id='1021'


tran_final_net_bal
2509.3
-30.7
-2478.6
```

The result should be 0

However If I use the following sql statement

```
select sum(tran_final_net_bal) AS tran_final_net_bal from transaction where tran_account_id='1021'
```

The return result was

```
tran_final_net_bal
4.54747350886464e-13
```

How can I fix this to get 0 which is the right answer in this  case.

tran_final_net_bal is of "double" type

Comment: What version of what RDBMS are you using? This doesn't appear to be  SQL Server.

Comment: Try casting select cast( sum(tran_final_net_bal) as decimal(10,2)) as total

Comment: The column name "tran_final_net_bal" sounds like you want to store money in that column. Is that really what you're doing?

Comment: If you're trying to store money, you need to fix the table, not the query. You need to use a data type like `numeric(n, m)` rather than `float` or `real`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is MySQL, then the query below will work.

```
select sum(CAST(tran_final_net_bal AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS tran_final_net_bal
from transaction
where tran_account_id='1021';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know what the acceptable precision is, you could try [rounding it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
select 
    ROUND(sum(tran_final_net_bal), 10) AS tran_final_net_bal 
from transaction where tran_account_id='1021'
```